# How to save and restore turtles and links without using an external file

Tags: graph, netlogo

I need to save all the turtles and links, so that if I make some modifications to the graph topology I'm able to restore it later. For now the method that I'm using is to load/save through an external file:

```
to save-graph
  nw:save-graphml "mygraph.graphml"
end

to load-graph
  ask turtles [ die ]
  nw:load-graphml "mygraph.graphml"
end
```

But it's very slow, specially for big graphs. I tried to simply assign the turtles and links to other variables:

```
globals [saved-turtles saved-links]

to save-graph
  set saved-turtles turtles
  set saved-links links
end

to load-graph
  set turtles saved-turtles
  set links saved-links
end
```

But it says that I cannot simply assign turtles and links this way:

[image]

And it highlights the line in which I set turtles and links. Is there a way to do it without using an external file?

Comment: `turtles` isn't a normal variable.  The only way that I knew how to fill it was by using commands such as `create-turtle` and `sprout`; I'd probably store all of the turtles' attributes and then recreate them using the attributes to do what you want, but using the nw extension is simpler.  However, graphml format takes up a lot of space and parsing a graphml file is nontrivial.  I wonder whether one of the other nw: load and save commands would be better.  There may be a way to save dead turtles without a file, but I think you'll have to wait until one of the developers wanders by (they do).

Comment: Do you want to restore only turtles and links or would it be sufficient to restore the complete model-state? If yes you could check the `export-world` and `import-world` primitives. It would also be stored in an external datafile but eventually it would be faster than the nw sotarge options? Just an idea.

Comment: I couldn't test the program myself because I don't have NL installed but have you tried using breeds instead of globals ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it can depend a lot on your goals and the differences between both versions of the graph. It is almost sure that the save/load graphml procedures are not the best ones to do it, and it is not possible to "keep" all the turtles and links with all their properties and restore them later... agentsets are very big data structures with references to real agents, not the real agents themselves (as far as I know), so if you change an agent later, the information about it in the agentset variable it is not of high value after that.

If you have only a small amount of differences between the versions of the graph and this graph is really big maybe it is better to add some new property (version, for example) to turtles and links to inform you about the version the element belongs to (for example, 0:old, 1:new, 2:both) and having a way programmed by you to restore the previous state easily and fast. In this way, you never erase an old element, only hide it to the new state, and you keep the real difference between states.

I've used a similar method in some operations to manage big graphs in previous NetLogo projects, and it works fine. Hope this will help you.